# Generate dart automatically within dart editor

Tags: compiler-construction, editor, dart

Given I have a nicely formatted dart code and I save it only when I want it to be compiled, how can make Dart Editor to compile my changes on save ?

Thanks,
M0nkey

Comment: What do you mean with `be compiled`? run `pub build`?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "compile".

Comment: to compile ( Tools -> Generate Javascript )

Comment: Can you provide some info about your use case. Maybe there are alternative solutions that might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Webstorm - http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

You can define a File watcher to trigger `pub build` everytime you save a file (and define which filenames should trigger the task - ie. only `.dart` files)

Comment: Nice, like it, could you provide a more monkey friendly guide for it

Comment: p.s. downloaded it successfully, installed and also configured dart sdk path, how do I set up File watcher for dart trigger ?!

Comment: go into file -> settings -> file watchers -> + (top right corner) -> dart2JS